# Поддомен на MODx — проблема с компонентами

Tags: modx, revo, поддомены

**Подскажите, как грамотно создать поддомен для сайта на CMS MODx Revo?**

Сейчас есть сайт site.ru, создан поддомен sub.site.ru. И всё работает замечательно, за исключением двух компонентов (TinyMCE и Sendex). У TinyMCE работают все элементы, кроме "Добавить ссылку" — выдает 404 ошибку.

Компонент Sendex не может создать рассылку (тоже 404 ошибка). В консоли браузера следующая строчка:

```
http://sub.site.ru/assets/components/sendex/connector.php 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Разумеется, все файлы на месте. 
Редиректы не настроены, файл .htaccess не изменялся.

Я понимаю, что как-то нужно исправить пути к этим файлам, если происходит обращение с поддомена (с основного домена эти файлы доступны). В файле config.ink.php указывается путь от основного домена:

```
../site.ru/sub/assets/...
```

Однако, на поддомене, соседние файлы в той же директории, что и проблемный файл connector.php, нормально открываются.
Например, у Sendex'a соседний:

```
/assets/components/sendex/index.html
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос с TinyMCE решил его удалением, и установкой альтернативного редактора CKEditor: [modx.com](https://modx.com/extras/package/CKEditor). Если я правильно понял, проблема оказалась в самом компоненте. Все функции нового редактора заработали, как должно.

По Sendex альтернативы не нашёл.